# Having difficulty using regexp in grep

Tags: regex, grep

I'm probably missing something really obvious but I have an xml file that I need to grep to see if it contains this:

**`<phone>null</phone>`**
or 
**`<phone></phone>`**

In any case, and with any additional spaces (between the tags).

So, my non working solution is this:

```
grep -i "\<phone\>\s*(null)?\s*\</phone\>" ./myfile.xml
```

But that returns empty (even though the file I'm using has this node).
What am I overlooking?

TIA

Comment: If you input is what you have there then your regex should work. I tested your regex with grep and it matched in both occasions.

Comment: yeah... I had to add the -P, my server must not be configured to use the perl regEx by default... don't know enough about it to speculate further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! Found it... I'll answer it myself in case anyone else finds it useful in the future... adding the **-P** switch ie...

```
grep -i -P "\<phone\>\s*(null)?\s*\</phone\>" ./myfile.xml
```

...to the call makes it use perl style regex (which is what I'm using) and produces the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
kent$  echo "<phone>null</phone> or <phone></phone>foo bar"|grep -iE "(<phone>null</phone>|<phone></phone>)"                             

<phone>null</phone> or <phone></phone>foo bar
```

Comment: Kent, I figured it out, thanks... but your solution doesn't use regular expressions or test for possible empty spaces around (in place of) the null.  Thanks though.